Which is correct: "as of today" or "from today" in the context of something coming into effect?
Can you please tell me which is correct: as of today or from today in the context of something coming into effect? For example:

Please add the car to my insurance policy as of today.
Please add the car to my insurance policy from toda.

If both are possible, do you sense a nuance of difference in meaning between the two?

As is often the case in English, preposition use is very flexible - as of today, from today, as from today, from today on, from today onward[s] are all equivalent for the "starting today" sense (but not all of them can be used to mean "up until today"). Any "nuance of difference" is more likely to be related to change over time, geographical regions, and a speaker / writer's sociolinguistic class, rather than semantics / meaning.

Another possibility would be effective today, though again with the caveat that accidents occuring before the time of the coverage request would be   a "pre-existing condition" and not covered.


Please add the car to my insurance policy as of today.

From context,  as of means from; the OP’s two versions hence mean the same.
For information, as of today has more than one meaning.  Two of them are as shown:

As of today can mean from the beginning up until now, including today:


As of today, only three survivors have been found.


... it can also mean starting today and going forward into the future:


As of today, all passengers must check their luggage before boarding the plane.

Britannica explains as of today.
Collins Dictionary also states multiple meanings similarly:

up to, on, or from (a specified time)

Edit
For insurance, as of (or 'from') today would mean as of (or 'from') the time today when the insurance cover is issued.

When I worked at an insurance company, we would only issue insurance covering the future, so 'as of/from today' would be expanded to 'as of/from the time today when we issued this cover'. So buying insurance at 10 AM today would not get you cover for the accident you had at 8 AM.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I've added the point about time.
